# How to pass an expression to a LINQ query as a parameter

Tags: .net, reflection, lambda

I have a few statements like these:

```
if (mediaCode.IndexOf(',') > 0) {
  entries = entries.Where(c => mediaCode.Contains(c.Mediacode));
}
else {
  entries = entries.Where(c => c.Mediacode == mediaCode);
}
```

then:

```
if (contentType.IndexOf(',') > 0) {
    entries = entries.Where(c => contentType.Contains(c.Contenttype));
}
else {
    entries = entries.Where(c => c.Contenttype == contentType);
}
```

I would like to create a function where i just pass the string and the property,
something like: MethodName(contentType, c.Contenttype)

How could this be done?

Comment: it is not clear what you're asking. Do you want to pass the Expression inside a Linq query to a method? e.g.: entries.Where(conditionParameter) where conditionParameter is c=> mediaCode.Contains(value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Reflection (see [How to get a property value based on the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508050/how-to-get-a-property-value-based-on-the-name)), you could do it like this:

```
    protected void FilterStrings(ref IEnumerable<StringStruct> entries, string contentType, string fieldName)
    {
        if (contentType.IndexOf(',') > 0)
        {
            entries = entries.Where(c => contentType.Contains(c.GetType().GetProperty(fieldName).GetValue(c, null).ToString()));
        }
        else
        {
            entries = entries.Where(c => c.GetType().GetProperty(fieldName).GetValue(c, null).ToString() == contentType);
        }
    }
```

You would call the function like this:

```
FilterStrings(ref entries, mediaCode, "Mediacode");
```