# Selecting object property with variable?

Tags: c#

I'm using an API which returns this JSON:

```
"Deadlines": {
        "Monday": "10:00:00",
        "Tuesday": "10:00:00",
        "Wednesday": "10:00:00",
        "Thursday": "10:00:00",
        "Friday": "10:00:00",
        "Saturday": null,
        "Sunday": null
    },
```

right now I can get a deadline time by using dot notation.

```
var deadline = _api.Select(x => x.Deadlines.Friday);
```

However, what I want, is to check which day it is today

```
var todaysDayOfWeek = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

and then use that variable as the property name.

However, I have absolutely no idea how to do this. I though that maybe I can use bracket notation, but I just get a "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type Deadlines. (Deadlines is just a model which has mon-sun timespan properties)

```
var todaysDayOfWeek = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
var deadline = _api.Select(x => x.Deadlines[todaysDayOfWeek]); // <-- produces aforementioned error
```

```
    public class Deadlines
    {
        public TimeSpan? Monday { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan? Tuesday { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan? Wednesday { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan? Thursday { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan? Friday { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan? Saturday { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan? Sunday { get; set; }
    }
```

How would one go about achieving this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a property value based on the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508050/how-to-get-a-property-value-based-on-the-name)

Comment: If you treat Deadlines like it's a dictionary instead of defining a different property for each day of the week, that will be a lot easier. `public Dictionary<string, TimeSpan?> Deadlines { get; set; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, maybe you should use a `Dictionary<DayOfWeek, TimeSpan?>` instead of multiple properties.

If that's not possible:

The efficient way, a `switch`:

```
public class Deadlines
{
    public TimeSpan? Monday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Tuesday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Wednesday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Thursday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Friday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Saturday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Sunday { get; set; }
    
    public TimeSpan? GetDeadLine(DayOfWeek dow)
    {
        switch(dow)
        {
            case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                return Monday;
            case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                return Tuesday;
            case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
                return Wednesday;
            case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
                return Thursday;
            case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                return Friday;
            case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                return Saturday;
            case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                return Sunday;
            default: throw new ArgumentException(nameof(dow));
        }
    }
}
```

---

Or you could have a dictionary that returns the deadline:

```
public class Deadlines
{
    public TimeSpan? Monday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Tuesday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Wednesday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Thursday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Friday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Saturday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Sunday { get; set; }

    private static readonly Dictionary<DayOfWeek, Func<Deadlines, System.TimeSpan?>> DayOfWeekMapper;
    static Deadlines()
    {
        DayOfWeekMapper = new Dictionary<System.DayOfWeek, Func<Deadlines, System.TimeSpan?>>
        {
            { DayOfWeek.Monday, dl => dl.Monday },{ DayOfWeek.Tuesday, dl => dl.Tuesday },{ DayOfWeek.Wednesday, dl => dl.Wednesday },
            { DayOfWeek.Thursday, dl => dl.Thursday },{ DayOfWeek.Friday, dl => dl.Friday },{ DayOfWeek.Saturday, dl => dl.Saturday },{ DayOfWeek.Sunday, dl => dl.Sunday }
        };
    }

    public TimeSpan? GetDeadline(DayOfWeek dow) => DayOfWeekMapper[dow].Invoke(this);
}
```

---

There's also reflection but i would not use it here since it's not efficient and not readable.

Well, here it is:

```
public class Deadlines
{
    public TimeSpan? Monday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Tuesday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Wednesday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Thursday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Friday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Saturday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Sunday { get; set; }

    private static readonly Dictionary<string,PropertyInfo> DayOfWeekPropertyMapper;
    static Deadlines()
    {
        DayOfWeekPropertyMapper = typeof(Deadlines).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(p => Enum.GetNames(typeof(DayOfWeek)).Contains(p.Name))
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p);
    }

    public TimeSpan? GetDeadline(string dayOfWeek) => (TimeSpan?)DayOfWeekPropertyMapper[dayOfWeek].GetValue(this);
}
```

With your sample:

```
string dow = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString(); 
IEnumerable<TimeSpan?> deadlines = _api.Select(x => x.Deadlines.GetDeadline(dow));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The switch statement suited me best :)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- The switch statement

  ```
  switch( dayOfWeek )
  {
      case Monday: return deadlines.Monday;
      case Tuesday: return deadlines.Tuesday;
      ...
  }
  ```
- Reflection.

  This is quite advanced, and mighty hacky, so I do not recommend it. It consists of getting the list of fields from `typeof(DayOfWeek)`, and for each one of them, checking whether the name of the field is the name you are looking for, and if so, obtaining the value of that field.  I am only mentioning it for completeness, I do not recommend using it, therefore I am skipping the exact details on how to do it.

Comment: Thank you! Based on another user's suggestion, I first used the reflection approach (which worked) but after reading your comment I changed it to the switch approach instead :) also considering that I read in the linked thread that using reflection is slow